# How to map a keyboard shortcut to CTRL+R in iTerm 2?

Tags: mac, terminal, vim, iterm2

I am trying to map the `Command + Shift + Z` shortcut to what vim uses for redo, `CTRL + R`:

[image]

What is the proper code I should enter in? It seems that `\c` is not the correct code, but I cannot find it on their website.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the **Send Text with "vim" Special Chars** option, just send the hexadecimal code for the [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) `CTRL+R` which is `0x12` as you can see from [this table](http://ascii-table.com/control-chars.php).

So to set it up for your desired combination of characters choose **Send Hex Code** and insert `0x12` as value:

[image]